# How to sort structs from least to greatest in C?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, data-structures, struct

1. The program needs to order the structures from least to greatest based on the zip element of each individual struct.
2. The input is based on input/output redirection. An example of an input.txt file is as follows:

> ```
> Jason Solis   
> 20294 Lorenzana Dr  
> Woodland Hills, CA   
> 91364   
> Robert Smith   
> 19831 Henshaw St   
> Culver City, CA   
> 94023   
> Bob Arum  
> 5142 Dumont Pl   
> Azusa, CA   
> 91112
> ```

code:

```
struct info {

    char name[BUFF_SIZE];                                
    char stAddress[BUFF_SIZE];                                      
    char cityAndState[BUFF_SIZE]; 
    char zip[BUFF_SIZE];
};

 void selectionSort(struct info *ptrStruct);




int main(void)
{

    int count;                       
    char buffer[600];
    struct info *ptrStruct[512];

    for (count = 0; count < 18; count++)
    {
        ptrStruct[count] = (struct info*) malloc(sizeof(struct info));  
        gets(buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->name, buffer);         
        gets(buffer);   
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->stAddress, buffer);    
        gets(buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->cityAndState, buffer); 
        gets(buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->zip, buffer);          
    }

    selectionSort(ptrStruct);

    printf("\n\nLEAST TO GREATEST\n");
    for (count = 0; count < 18; count++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->name);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->stAddress);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->cityAndState);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->zip);
    }
}

void selectionSort(struct info *ptrStruct[])
{

    int count2;
    int count1;
    int minIndex;
    struct info *ptrTemporary;      

    for (count2 = 0; count2 < 18 - 1; count2++)
    {
        minIndex = count2;
        for (count1 = count2 + 1; count1 < 18; count1++)
        {
            if (strcmp(ptrStruct[count1]->zip, ptrStruct[minIndex]->zip) < 0)
                minIndex = count1;
        }
        ptrTemporary = ptrStruct[count2];
        ptrStruct[count2] = ptrStruct[minIndex];
        ptrStruct[minIndex] = ptrTemporary;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `STRUCT_SIZE`?

Comment: access the elements and then sort them

Comment: The STRUCT_SIZE I just changed it to 512.

Comment: @RodEfraim: Hu, 18 would do, wouldn't it?

Comment: replace `== -1` with `< 0`

Comment: BLUEPIXY ok I see.

Comment: And must so as not to search the already  sorted part.

Comment: Ok, finally: Here's the bug `selectionSort(ptrStruct);` this call should make the compiler yell out in pain.

Comment: I hope those names in the input file aren't real.

Comment: never use `gets`. Also, what's wrong with the standard `qsort`, with a simple sorting function?

Comment: The big mistake I have made is that I was passing a pointer into the selectionSort function instead of passing the array of pointers! Now my program does not crash. Unfortunately the program still  does not output the addresses from least to greatest. I will have to do more modifying around the strcmp() string function that is in the selectionSort() function. I believe the current program just compares the first char of each zip code instead of comparing all of the chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 32
#define STRUCT_SIZE 512

struct info {
    char name[BUFF_SIZE];
    char stAddress[BUFF_SIZE];
    char cityAndState[BUFF_SIZE]; 
    char zip[BUFF_SIZE];
};

void selectionSort(struct info *ptrStruct[], int size);//!

int main(void){
    int count, size;//!
    char buffer[600];
    struct info *ptrStruct[STRUCT_SIZE];

    for (count = 0; count < STRUCT_SIZE; count++){
        ptrStruct[count] = (struct info*) malloc(sizeof(struct info));
        if(EOF==scanf("%599[^\n]%*c", buffer)){//!
            free(ptrStruct[count]);
            break;
        };
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->name, buffer);
        scanf("%599[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->stAddress, buffer);
        scanf("%599[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->cityAndState, buffer);
        scanf("%599[^\n]%*c", buffer);
        strcpy(ptrStruct[count]->zip, buffer);
    }

    size = count;//!
    selectionSort(ptrStruct, size);//!

    printf("\n\nLEAST TO GREATEST\n");
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)//!
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->name);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->stAddress);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->cityAndState);
        printf("%s\n", ptrStruct[count]->zip);
        free(ptrStruct[count]);
    }
}

void selectionSort(struct info *ptrStruct[], int size)//!
{
    int count1, count2;
    int minIndex;
    struct info *ptrTemporary;

    for (count2 = 0; count2 < size -1; count2++)//!
    {
        minIndex = count2;
        for (count1 = count2 + 1; count1 < size; count1++)//!
        {
            if (strcmp(ptrStruct[count1]->zip, ptrStruct[minIndex]->zip) < 0)//!
                minIndex = count1;
        }
        if(minIndex != count2){
            ptrTemporary = ptrStruct[count2];//!
            ptrStruct[count2] = ptrStruct[minIndex];
            ptrStruct[minIndex] = ptrTemporary;//!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind I see the big mistake I have made is that I was passing a pointer into the selectionSort function instead of passing the array of pointers! Now my program does not crash.

Comment: It won't let me accept because I'm a noob right now. I don't have enough reputation points to vote for you! Thanks again.